# Error installing ruby gem ibm_db with DB2 client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, db2

I am getting the following error:

```
gem install ibm_db
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ibm_db:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ibm_db-3.0.4/ext
C:/Ruby21-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20171018-4480-1i7vx9n.rb extconf.rb
Detected 64-bit Ruby

Detected usage of IBM Data Server Driver package. Ensure you have downloaded 64-bit package of IBM_Data_Server_Driver and retry the 'gem install ibm_db' command

creating gil_release_version
creating unicode_support_version
checking for SQLConnect() in -ldb2cli... yes
checking for gil_release_version... yes
checking for unicode_support_version... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ibm_db-3.0.4/ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ibm_db-3.0.4/ext
make "DESTDIR="
generating ibm_db-x64-mingw32.def
compiling ibm_db.c
In file included from C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlcli.h:983:0,
                 from C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlcli1.h:45,
                 from ruby_ibm_db_cli.h:52,
                 from ibm_db.c:27:
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1748:5: error: unknown type name '__in_ecount'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1751:5: error: unknown type name '__out_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1754:5: error: unknown type name '__out_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1865:5: error: unknown type name '__in_ecount'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1868:5: error: unknown type name '__out_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1871:5: error: unknown type name '__out_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1891:5: error: unknown type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1894:5: error: unknown type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1897:5: error: unknown type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1900:5: error: unknown type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1907:5: error: unknown type name '__out_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1909:5: error: unknown type name '__out_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1911:5: error: unknown type name '__out_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1913:5: error: unknown type name '__out_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1920:5: error: unknown type name '__out_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1922:5: error: unknown type name '__out_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1927:5: error: unknown type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1930:5: error: unknown type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1933:5: error: unknown type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1936:5: error: unknown type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1939:5: error: unknown type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1942:5: error: unknown type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1952:5: error: unknown type name '__in_ecount'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1954:5: error: unknown type name '__out_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1961:5: error: unknown type name '__out_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1971:5: error: unknown type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1974:5: error: unknown type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1977:5: error: unknown type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1983:5: error: unknown type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1986:5: error: unknown type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1989:5: error: unknown type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1992:5: error: unknown type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:1998:5: error: unknown type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:2001:5: error: unknown type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:2004:5: error: unknown type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:2018:5: error: unknown type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:2021:5: error: unknown type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:2024:5: error: unknown type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:2031:5: error: unknown type name '__out_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:2034:5: error: unknown type name '__out_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:2036:5: error: unknown type name '__out_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:2039:5: error: unknown type name '__out_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:2087:5: error: unknown type name '__out'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:2128:5: error: unknown type name '__in_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:2129:5: error: unknown type name '__out_bcount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include/sqlext.h:2130:5: error: unknown type name '__in'
ibm_db.c:104:0: warning: "STRCASECMP" redefined [enabled by default]
In file included from c:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from ibm_db.c:21:
c:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1783:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
ibm_db.c: In function '_ruby_ibm_db_free_conn_struct':
ibm_db.c:490:7: warning: variable 'rc' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_Ruby_Thread_Call':
ibm_db.c:696:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'rb_thread_call_without_gvl' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
ibm_db.c: In function '_ruby_ibm_db_free_stmt_handle_and_resources':
ibm_db.c:718:7: warning: variable 'rc' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
ibm_db.c: In function '_ruby_ibm_db_assign_options':
ibm_db.c:1430:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
ibm_db.c:1513:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
ibm_db.c: In function '_ruby_ibm_db_connect_helper2':
ibm_db.c:2181:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
ibm_db.c:2360:41: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
ibm_db.c: In function '_ruby_ibm_db_connect_helper':
ibm_db.c:2538:26: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_createDBNX':
ibm_db.c:3255:9: warning: unused variable 'return_value' [-Wunused-variable]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_autocommit':
ibm_db.c:3328:37: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
ibm_db.c: In function '_ruby_ibm_db_bind_parameter_helper':
ibm_db.c:6232:30: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
ibm_db.c:6256:53: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_execute':
ibm_db.c:7108:73: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_field_type':
ibm_db.c:8415:30: warning: initialization discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
ibm_db.c:8438:15: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
ibm_db.c:8446:15: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
ibm_db.c:8449:15: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
ibm_db.c:8452:15: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
ibm_db.c:8455:15: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
ibm_db.c:8458:15: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
ibm_db.c:8461:15: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
ibm_db.c:8464:15: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
ibm_db.c:8467:15: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_result_cols':
ibm_db.c:10126:9: warning: unused variable 'ret_val' [-Wunused-variable]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_server_info':
ibm_db.c:11252:17: warning: the comparison will always evaluate as 'false' for the address of 'connection' will never be NULL [-Waddress]
ibm_db.c: At top level:
ibm_db.c:48:13: warning: '_ruby_ibm_db_set_decfloat_rounding_mode_client' declared 'static' but never defined [-Wunused-function]
ibm_db.c:49:14: warning: '_ruby_ibm_db_instance_name' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
ibm_db.c:2592:12: warning: '_ruby_ibm_db_set_decfloat_rounding_mode_client_helper' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
ibm_db.c: In function '_ruby_ibm_db_connect_helper2':
ibm_db.c:2433:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_Ruby_Thread_Call':
ibm_db.c:710:3: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
make: *** [ibm_db.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ibm_db-3.0.4 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.1.0/ibm_db-3.0.4/gem_make.out
```

I am trying to develop in local Ruby on Rails to a remote DB2 database, I have set global variables pointing to my DB2 cli and db2dsdriver.cfg config file with connection settings. 
I have tried also with IBM data server driver package and cli is not detected.
Any advice? How can I install the ibm_db gem and connect to DB2??

======LoG: ===========================================================

```
gil_release_version is:
/* begin */
1: #ifndef GIL_RELEASE_VERSION
2: #define GIL_RELEASE_VERSION
3: #endif
/* end */

unicode_support_version is:
/* begin */
1: #ifndef UNICODE_SUPPORT_VERSION
2: #define UNICODE_SUPPORT_VERSION
3: #endif
/* end */

have_library: checking for SQLConnect() in -ldb2cli... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. "-IC:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include" -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby21-x64/lib -L"C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/lib" -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby210  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. "-IC:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include" -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby21-x64/lib -L"C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/lib" -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby210 -ldb2cli  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:57: error: 'SQLConnect' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:16:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
conftest.c:16:32: warning: variable 'p' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))SQLConnect; return 0; }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. "-IC:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include" -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby21-x64/lib -L"C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/lib" -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby210 -ldb2cli  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'SQLConnect' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { SQLConnect(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_header: checking for gil_release_version... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -E -IC:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. "-IC:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include" -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <gil_release_version>
/* end */

--------------------

have_header: checking for unicode_support_version... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -E -IC:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. "-IC:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB/include" -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <unicode_support_version>
/* end */

--------------------
```

I am using...

- Ruby 2.1.5
- Devkit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx
- Gem ibm_db 3.0.4 x86-mingw32
- IBM data server client 10.5
- Over Windows 10

RubyGems Environment:

> ```
>       - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.13
>       - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.5 (2014-11-13 patchlevel 273) [x64-mingw32]
>       - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
>       - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Users/mypc/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
>       - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby21-x64/bin/ruby.exe
>       - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby21-x64/bin
>       - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: C:/Users/mypc/.gem/specs
>       - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: C:/ProgramData
>       - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
>         - ruby
>         - x64-mingw32
>       - GEM PATHS:
>          - C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
>          - C:/Users/mypc/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
>       - GEM CONFIGURATION:
>          - :update_sources => true
>          - :verbose => true
>          - :backtrace => false
>          - :bulk_threshold => 1000
>       - REMOTE SOURCES:
>          - https://rubygems.org/
>       - SHELL PATH:
>          - C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\
>          - C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\
>          - C:\Windows\system32
>          - C:\Windows
>          - C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
>          - C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
>          - C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
>          - C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
>          - C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
>          - C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
>          - C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN
>          - C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\FUNCTION
>          - C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\SAMPLES\REPL
>          - C:\Ruby23-x64\bin
>          - C:\Ruby24-x64\bin
>          - C:\Ruby21-x64\bin
>          - C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
> ```

Comment: When the compilation starts, what is the full value of the INCLUDE environment variable?   Can you prove that the directory that contains the Db2 nclude-files exists, and is populated, and is accessible to the account running the compile, and that directory is on the INCLUDE environment variable path?

Comment: I´ve INCLUDE system variable with values C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\INCLUDE and C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\LIB and IBM_DB_INCLUDE with C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\include value. C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\include route exists.

Comment: The evidence suggests that the compiler is not finding the files sqlcli.h,  sqlcli1.h, sqlext.h etc. Or it is finding them but there is a missing #define somewhere.  *VERIFY* your assumptions. This is most likely your configuration mistake.

Comment: Any guide to check installation steps? where should be #define? I added INCLUDE and IBM_DB_INCLUDE variables to my user, they where in system and same result. This steps aren´t automatic with client installation? thanks

Comment: Maybe a compatibility problem? Ruby DB2 compatibility list?

 irb(main):001:0> require 'ibm_db' 
NotImplementedError: ibm_db with Ruby 2.1 64-bit on Windows platform is not supported. Refer to README for details
x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require' etc
Readme says,Note:
1) Currently Ruby-2.0 64-bit version on Windows is not supported as there are issues related to SQL definitions with the mingW compiler 
Details can be found here https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/2041/ 
 Support will be enabled after the abive reported issue is resolved

Comment: As the ibm_db (at current version 3.0.4) does not support 64-bit Ruby on Windows, but it does support a Windows 32-bit Ruby, are you able to use a 32-bit build?  I notice that IBM DB2 V11 ships with ibm_db-2.5.18-x86-mingw32.gem, are you able to use that ?  If not, it looks like you have to wait for that issue with SAL in mingw and the Db2 header files to be resolved.

Comment: If you replace the "specstrings.h" file in the mys64 tree by the current version of the same file from https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mingw-org-wsl/ci/4.0-dev/tree/include/specstrings.h then the compilation with mingw of ibm_db 3.0.4 may complete successfully .  Don't know if it is useful however.

Comment: I can successfully install with new specstrings.h but i get error when running.
First it says there is not mswin32/ibm_db.rb, if i copy that direc, i get error. 
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ibm_db-2.5.18/lib/mswin32/ibm_db.rb:8:in `<top (required)>': ibm_db with Ruby 2.0 64-bit on Windows platform is not supported. Refer to README for more details (NotImplementedError)
thanks, maybe its not posible

Comment: You are unlikely to succeed with downlevel Ruby, and downlevel ibm_db. Consider using latest Ruby source and most recent ibm_db. It may still fail, but in a different manner. You should maybe engage via github. Seems too few devs are working on this combination (Winx64/Rubyx64/ibm_dbx64/minGW) so you are on your own, it seems. If Ruby is important to you, consider a pure 32-bit (rubyx32,ibm_db(x32), db2-client x32) until such time as the devs sort it out. I suspect stackoverflow is not the correct forum for this.